# Unable to run batch file located on mapped network drive

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am unable to run batch file that is located in mapped network drive using System.Diagnostics.Process in VB.Net.  I get:

```
'<batchfilename>.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
Press any key to continue...
```

I get the same error when navigate to the folder (using explorer) that contains this batch file and double click it.  I can successfully run the batch file by changing the directory to that folder through command prompt.  I can't figure out why this is happening.  I think the problem is Start() function of Process works like double click rather than just run the batch file.  I have put my code below.  Any help regarding this will be much appreciated.

```
Private WithEvents batchProcObj As New Process
Private Const SLEEP_AMOUNT As Integer = 100
Public Event Exited As EventHandler
Private eventHandled As Boolean

Public Sub startBatchProcess(ByVal batchProcFilePath As String, ByVal batchParams As String, ByVal domainName As String, ByVal loginName As String, ByVal passwd As String)
        ' Initialise process start info with batch process path and the parameters
        Dim startInfoObj As New ProcessStartInfo()
        Dim parentDir As New IO.DirectoryInfo(batchProcFilePath)

        ' Initialise event to false
        eventHandled = False

        ' Get the batch file name without the extension
        batchName = batchProcFilePath

        Try                
            ' Assign the batch process properties
            startInfoObj.FileName = batchProcFilePath
            startInfoObj.Arguments = batchParams
            startInfoObj.UseShellExecute = False
            startInfoObj.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
            startInfoObj.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Windows\System32\"
            startInfoObj.Domain = domainName
            startInfoObj.UserName = loginName
            startInfoObj.Password = appHandler.getSecureString(passwd)
            startInfoObj.LoadUserProfile = True
            batchProcObj.StartInfo = startInfoObj
            batchProcObj.EnableRaisingEvents = True

            ' Start the batch file
            batchProcObj.Start()

            ' Get the start time of the batch process
            procStartTime = batchProcObj.StartTime
            ' Insert audit log
            appHandler.writeAuditLog("RunBatchProcess", "START - Batch Process [" & batchName & "]")

        Catch ex As Exception
            appHandler.writeErrorLog("Start Batch Process: " & batchProcFilePath, ex)
        End Try

        ' Continue running the batch process till it exits
        Do While Not eventHandled
            elapsedTime += SLEEP_AMOUNT
            Thread.Sleep(SLEEP_AMOUNT)
        Loop

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `FileIO.FileSystem` and copy that into temp file.
Then use `Backgroundworker` to run.